# Web Intelligence Returning measures

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Hi I am new to business objects. My question is how do created a variable that returns unique measures based on an object. I know there are functions min and max that returns the smallest and largest measures, but what if I want the third value or the fourth measure. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. It a webi report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite as easy as it should be.  This is best illustrated with an example.  I'll create a sample report from Island Reports Marketing, and include `Country`, `Service`, and `Revenue`.  Let's say we want to get the third-lowest Service Revenue by Country:

[image]

So we want to see 32,640 for France, and 73,280 for US.  We remove the `Service` column from the report, and change the formula for the Revenue column to:

```
=[Revenue] In ([Country];[Service]) Where ((Rank([Revenue];[Service];Bottom;[Country]))=3)
```

This produces:

[image]

If you want to see the Service that's associated with the ranked Revenue, you have to create a similar formula.  Drag Service back into the report, and change its formula to:

```
=[Service] Where ((Rank([Revenue];[Service];Bottom;[Country]))=3)
```

This produces:

[image]

(if you left it as [Service], you would get all values, but all rows other than Restaurant and Poolside Bar would have a blank Revenue)

To display a different nth ranked value, just change the "3" at the end of each formula.  Remove `;Bottom` to rank from highest.

Comment: if there were multiple values in the Service column - just say US has Restaurant and a poolside bar that has revenue of 73280. Is it possible to concatenate them and have them in the same row? @Joe

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that in the report. Only way would be with a derived table in the universe.